# Power BI using Manage Roles to Return Multiple Selections

Tags: powerbi, dax, roles

I hope I'm just missing something simple but I've  had no luck figuring this out so far;

My report needs restricting by who is looking at it, hence using the 'Manage Roles'.

The **Clients** are A, B and C

There are two **Users**

Person 1 can access A & B

Person 2 can access A & C

My Table is'*ClientRestrictor*'

| Email | Client_Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1, 2 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |

relationship is one to one (*ClientRestrictor* to *Clients*)

In manage roles I currently have ;

```
UserPrincipalName() = [Email]
```

But this only works to show Client B for User 1 and Client C for User 2

I tried using Find to match without success

```
Find(UserPrincipalName(), [Email]) > 0
```

Can anyone suggest how I can have both users able to access client A's data?
Thanks

NB: Splitting the first row out result in error when trying to refresh, 'duplicate value is not allowed'

Comment: if you have multiple email in column then this UserPrincipalName() = [Email] cant work;
Because you compare a@organization.com, b@organization.com = a@organization.com -> this is false!
One row, one email!

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to respond, you appear to have misread the question though. I'm asking how do I change the Manage Roles so that it does work. Obviously it doesn't work, that's why I'm here asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. First, you can try to replace comma separated string to pipeline separated where we can use PATHCONTAINS:

https://dax.guide/pathcontains/

```
PATHCONTAINS(SUBSTITUTE(access[Email],",","|"), UserPrincipalName() )
```

Or you can modify your table '*ClientRestrictor*'

| Email | Client_Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |

Comment: Many thanks! The first suggestion worked, though I did need to take out the space after the separating comma.

Comment: Yes that's right, we need to get rid of the spaces